# How to view top command for particular process without missing headline?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface

I am running top command and the result is as below.

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
12446 root      20   0 9869844 6.538g 381348 S 181.2 56.1   2136:08 myps
5019 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   1.3  0.0 426:58.00 kipmi0
```

I would like to see only myps ,so i used grep as below

```
top | grep myps
```

The result looks below

```
12446 root      20   0 9869844 6.538g 381348 S 181.2 56.1   2136:08 myps
```

I need header(title ) also need to be displayed. What is the option to do it?

Update:
Following answer from the source question worked for me

```
top -p "$(pgrep -d ',' myps)"
```

Comment: From one of the answers in the other question, do `top -p "$(pgrep -d ',' myps)"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use top’s filtering to focus on a few processes.

```
$ top
```

Then type 'o/O', a prompt will appear inside *top* interface. 
Here, you can write filter expressions for example :

```
COMMAND=myps        //to get processes containing 'myps' in COMMAND attribute
!COMMAND=myps       //to get processes which do not contain 'myps' in COMMAND attribute
```

Comment: For resetting the filter, press `=` and then type your new filter with `o` again; Otherwise every time you press `o` the current filter would apply to the results of the previous filter (leads to nested filters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use extended grep to get the header line as well something like:

```
top | grep -E '(PID|myps)'
```

You could also bypass top and use watch like:

```
watch -n 1 bash -c "ps aux | grep -E '([P]ID|[m]yps)'"
```